# How to use sum and groupBy in laravel query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I want to sum stock in purchase table with different unit name in Laravel 5.6 This is my query:

```
DB::select("select brand_name,unit_name, sum(now_stock) as stock from purchases where category_id = 2 group By(unit_name)");
```

When I run it in mysql then it is OK, but when I use it in laravel then an error is shown.

**I want as out put in laravel blade file**

```
 1. brand_name ...Unit_name ...Stock
 2. BSRM ...  ........    1.2     ....  .. ..........25  
 3. KSRM..............1.5...................50
```

How can I write this query?

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this:

- Create a `Purchase` model first.

And use the model to query your DB.

```
Purchase::select([
        'brand_name',
        'unit_name',
        'sum(now_stock) as stock',
    ])
    ->where('category_id', 2)
    ->groupBy('unit_name')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use,

```
$purchase = DB::table('purchases')
               ->where('category_id',2)
               ->select('brand_name','unit_name',DB::raw('sum(now_stock) as stock'))
               ->groupBy('unit_name')
               ->get();
```

If you have a model named **Purchase** for **purchases** table , then use,

```
$purchase = Purchase::where('category_id',2)
                    ->select('brand_name','unit_name',DB::raw('sum(now_stock) as stock'))
                    ->groupBy('unit_name')
                    ->get();
```

You have to, pass this to your blade view for accessing it there. 
For that,

```
return view('bladeviewname', ['purchases' => $purchase]);
```

In your view, you can use like,

```
@foreach($purchases as $purchase)
  {{ $purchase->brand_name }}
  {{ $purchase->unit_name }}
  {{ $purchase->stock }}
@endforeach
```